# Difference between このような and こんな

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

What is the difference between このような and こんな?
How is their usage and different?
How semantically are they different?

Answer (score 4):

They are to some extent interchangeable. This [thesaurus entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/15767/meaning/m0u/) says (bold added):

> １ **「こんな」が、対象を身近に感じている表現である**のに対して、「こういう」「このよう」は、「こんな」よりも客観的である。したがって、「こんな人とは思わなかった」と「こういう人とは思わなかった」をくらべると、前者は、「人」に対する話者の感想(いい人だ、腹黒い人だ、など)を意味し、後者は、「人」の状態の説明(自分に親切にしてくれた、自分にいじわるをした、など)を意味する。
>
> ２  **対象への身近さはマイナスの評価を伴いやすいので、「こんな人」といった場合、ほめる意味ではなく、けなす意味になることが多い。**

As the above says, こんな implies more often the speaker's negative feeling about the object whereas このような can be used more neutrally. That said, このような can be used negatively and こんな can be used positively:

- このようなことになるとは思わなかった I didn't think it would result in a thing like this (bad).
- こんなたいそうなものをもらった　I received such a great gift.

So I guess you need not worry too much about the difference, but こんな is generally more colloquial and you need to be careful about how you use it. It may be safer to use このような if you are not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Both meanings are exactly the same "like this." Just「このような」sounds formal and 「こんな」sounds casual.